# Why it won't pass the string to input field but it shows in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When it loads, I can see the KEY just like this
`Your Key: shf8tg382kds`
However, Key won't appear in the input field.
Why? and How can I solve this?

**JavaScript Part**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        $(".chat#key").val($('#peer-id').text()).focus()
    }
</script>
```

**HTML part**

```
<p>Your Key : <span id="peer-id"></span> </p>

<input class="chat" id="key" name="messages[body]" placeholder="Type your Key Here!" type="text" />
```

**UPDATE**

If I change it to this, It shows `abc` in the input field.

```
$(".chat#key").val('abc').focus()
```

Comment: Any chance you have more than one `.chat#key`?

Comment: works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/bmDh6/. perhaps jquery was not imported when it was called

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes of course. but how does it help?

Comment: @user3678068 well it's weird.  I'm obtaining `peer-id` by using PeerJS. So it will be defined after loading page.  This is really weird.

Comment: @user3678068 In output HTML, you won't be able to see the key. But Key is visible when you see a page.

Comment: Then, that's your problem.  You can only have one element with a given id.  If you have more than one, selectors using that id will not work reliably.

Comment: `load` doesn't help here, you should use a callback function which is executed when the key is retrieved/generated.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm confident that there's only one element named `.chat#key'

Comment: and `$(".chat#key")` doesn't care about unique IDs, so this is not the main problem.

Comment: The weirdness is that key appears on the page when after load. But not in input field...

Comment: Is there any way to bring javascript to 'value' of input field? somethings like `<input value="<javascript:******>"`?

Comment: As long as it focuses the input field, it seems the script is working but it is not passing the parameter to the input field.

Comment: If you're duplicating the id, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: I believe when `$(".chat#key").val($('#peer-id').text()).focus()`  is executed, the key is not generated yet and `text` returns an empty string. Please read the docs of the library that you are using. Probably you should listen to an event.

Comment: @undefined I'm guessing so too. is there any good idea to make it delayed intentionally?

Comment: You are using JavaScript, an event-based language, using delays is not the proper of way of doing this, you should listen to an event and use a callback. http://peerjs.com/docs/#peeron